# Examples of Differential Forms on a $n$-dimensional TORUS.

Tags: differential-geometry

My text book asks me to show some examples of differential forms on a $n$-dimensional Torus.

What I have done: Let's take for example $S^1$. I'm confused since I saw differential forms given by a restriction of differential forms of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But I also saw them expressed like $\partial \theta$. For example on $T_2$ I saw one expressed as $\partial \theta \wedge \partial \eta$ that integrated on the whole torus gives the volume.

How can them be expressed in a proper way? Via immersion in $\mathbb{R}^m$? Via $\partial$angles multiplied for some infinitely derivable functions over the torus as in the euclidean case? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, good luck with differential manifolds. I think everything is there :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Integration
" A general 1-form is a linear combination of these differentials ... "

Comment: Is $sin(2\pi \theta)\partial \theta + sin^2(2\pi \theta)cos(2\pi \theta)\partial\eta$ a differential form on $T_2$?

Comment: yes https://math.colorado.edu/~jnc/lecture1.pdf
I'm not an expert, but think to "what is it useful for ?" why do they annoy me with all these abstract definitions ? think first to the differential 1-forms $df$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then of the sphere and to the corresponding result of $\int_a^b df$ and $\int_a^b g \ df$. realize that from a differential form we can define a minimal length between $a$ and $b$ : $\min_{\gamma:a\to b} \left| \int_\gamma df \right|$,  stretching (by a smooth real valued function) a differential form is in some sort equivalent to stretch the manifold itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Let $\Lambda \subset \Reals^{n}$ be a lattice (discrete additive subgroup) of full rank. If $p:\Reals^{n} \to T = \Reals^{n}/\Lambda$ is the quotient map, then every differential $k$-form $\omega$ on $T$ pulls back to a $\Lambda$-invariant $k$-form $p^{*}\omega$ on $\Reals^{n}$. Conversely, every $\Lambda$-invariant $k$-form on $\Reals^{n}$ arises in this way, i.e., "pushes forward" to a $k$-form on $T$.

In the case of $S^{1} = \Reals/2\pi\mathbf{Z}$, for example, $0$-forms are in bijective correspondence with $2\pi$-periodic functions on $\Reals$, and $1$-forms correspond to $1$-forms $f(x)\, dx$ with $f$ a real-valued function on $\Reals$ of period $2\pi$. Every smooth $1$-form is closed, but it's a pleasant exercise to show the $1$-form corresponding to $f(x)\, dx$ is exact if and only if
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\, dx = 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm trying to prove the last statement: of course $f(x)dx$ is closed. If it is exact then exists $F$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$ and $\partial F = f(x)dx$. The integral is thus equal to $F(2\pi)-F(0)$ and since we are on $S^1$ it is $0$. Is that right? How to reverse?

Comment: Yes, that's right. For the converse, put $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)\, dt$ and use the integral condition to deduce $F$ is $2\pi$-periodic (hence descends to a smooth function $F$ on the circle).

Comment: What is the formal definition of "pushes forward"? I think I get what it means conceptually, but I'm not exactly sure about the details.

Comment: The term is used informally, hence the quotation marks. (Differential forms do not push forward under smooth mappings.) To make matters precise here, if $\phi$ is a $\Lambda$-invariant $k$-form, $U$ is an open ball in the torus $T$, and $q_{1}$, $q_{2}:U \to \mathbf{R}^{n}$ denote sections of $p$ over $U$ (so $q_{2} - q_{1}$ is a constant vector in $\Lambda$), then the pullbacks are equal: $q_{1}^{*}\phi = q_{2}^{*}\phi$.